# Django logging setting configuration issue

Tags: django, logging, error-handling, error-logging, django-settings

My Logging settings is like below:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': LOG_ROOT + "/logfile",
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'console':{
            'level':'INFO',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'WARN',
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'home': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

I am calling it like

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('home')
log.error("Hey there it works!!")
```

getting error `No handlers could be found for logger "home"`

Seems I am missing something during configuration, also went through the past SQ questions to figure it out, but couldn't figure it out.

What is wrong, any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: Please try this: set `handlers` to `['console']` for the `home` logger and try again.

Comment: I didnt get it, can you write the full property of the configuration?

Comment: You mean 'handlers': ['console'] ?

Comment: still getting .. No handlers could be found for logger "home" :(